Question about complex logarithm
We define complex logarithm $\mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{0\right\}\to\left\{a+b\mathrm{i}\mid a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in(-\pi,\pi]\right\}$ by
$$
\log{z} := \log{|z|} + \mathrm{i}\arg{z}, 
\qquad \arg{z}\in(-\pi,\pi]. 
$$
Then, we consider its derivative, $\arg z_0\in(-\pi,\pi), z_0\ne0$:
$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{\log z - \log z_0}{z - z_0} 
= \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{\log z - \log z_0}{\mathrm{e}^{\log z} - \mathrm{e}^{\log z_0}} 
= \lim_{u \to \log z_0} \frac{u - \log z_0}{\mathrm{e}^u - \mathrm{e}^{\log z_0}} 
= \frac{1}{z_0}. 
$$
Hence, we have that $(\log z)' = \dfrac{1}{z}$, when $z\ne0$. So we have that
$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z=0, 
\qquad \gamma = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}, 
\qquad \theta \in [-\pi,\pi]
$$
However, it is obvious that
$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi\mathrm{i}.
$$
I wonder what my error is?

your $\log$ is not continuous on the negative real axis. Anyway, almost all basic issues with log comes from this.


Hence, we have that $(\log z)' = \dfrac{1}{z}$, when $z\ne0$.

That is not what you proved above. You've shown $\log'(z) = \dfrac{1}{z}$ when $\arg z\in(−\pi,\pi),z\neq 0$ (your own hypotheses the line just above). So $\log'(z) = \dfrac{1}{z}$ for $z\in \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$. So $\log$ is not a complex primitive of $z\mapsto\dfrac 1z$ on your whole contour $\gamma$, since $-1\in \gamma$. Therefore the reasoning you used cannot be applied. I should also mention as user peek-a-boo pointed out in comments, we don't even have continuity of $\log$ on points of $(-\infty,0)$.
